# How to create a migration that drops a table and removes an index in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Sometime back someone created a migration like this.

db/migrate/20150417172111_create_api_keys.rb

```
class CreateApiKeys < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :api_keys do |t|
      t.string :access_token

      t.references :user, index: true

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

This is what happened to the schema.

db/schema.rb

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20150417172111) do

  create_table "api_keys", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "access_token"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.datetime "created_at",   null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",   null: false
  end

  add_index "api_keys", ["user_id"], name: "index_api_keys_on_user_id"
```

Now it's been decided to remove the api_keys functionality. 
How do I drop the table and the api_keys index? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can generate a new migration with `rails generate migration drop_api_keys` and use:

```
def change
  remove_index :api_keys, column: :user_id
  drop_table :api_keys
end
```

Comment: Good answer, but wouldn't you want to do the `remove_index` first?

Answer (score 1):

```
def down
    remove_index :api_keys, :index_api_keys_on_user_id
    drop_table :api_keys
end
```

for complete reference you can check this [API doc](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.2.1/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements/remove_index)

Also you can refer this [ActiveRecord Migration Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html)

Hope it helps!!